# Asignar de nombre a una variable, el valor de otra variable

Tags: php

Quisiera saber como crear una variable cuyo valor sea el de $prueba2

```
$prueba = "Hola";
$prueba2 = &$prueba;
$$prueba2; // Debería valer $Hola pero me da un error.
```

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías concatenar el resultado $prueba2 = "&".$prueba

Comment: Qué error te da? estás seguro que existe la variable $Hola, inclúyela en tu código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tú quieres asignar una variable `$Hola` a partir de un string `Hola` que está en una variable. Para eso puedes hacer:

```
$prueba  = 'Hola';
$$prueba = 'Funcioné';

var_dump($Hola);
```

Y eso imprime "Funcioné".

Lo que estás haciendo ahora

```
$prueba = "Hola";
$prueba2 = &$prueba;
$$prueba2;
```

Se descompone en:

```
// declaro la variable $prueba con valor 'Hola'
$prueba = "Hola";

// declaro la variable $prueba2 como una referencia a $prueba
$prueba2 = &$prueba;

// Escribo $$prueba2 que se interpreta como $Hola
$$prueba2;
```

Y eso por debajo tira un error:

```
 E_NOTICE  Undefined variable: Hola
```

## Bonus Track

Ahora, por si a alguien le queda la curiosidad de qué efecto tiene el uso del `&` al declarar `$prueba2` el definirla como una referencia implica que:

```
$prueba  = 'Hola';
$prueba2 = &$prueba;
$prueba  = 'Chao';
var_dump($prueba2);
```

Imprime 'Chao'. Al redefinir `$prueba` por referencia se redefine `$prueba2`. Sin no la pasas como referencia:

```
$prueba  = 'Hola';
$prueba2 = $prueba;
$prueba  = 'Chao';
var_dump($prueba2);
```

Imprime 'Hola', porque `$prueba2` se declaró como el valor de `$prueba` y si redefines ésta, al intérprete le da lo mismo. `$prueba2` ya se evaluó.

Este comportamiento aplica a los escalares. Sin embargo, los objetos (incluyendo las instancias de una clase, que son objetos) se asignan siempre por referencia:

```
// esto crea un objeto en memoria, y $prueba es una referencia al objeto
$prueba = (object) ['saludo' => 'hola', 'despedida' => 'chao'];

// $prueba2 no es el valor del objeto, sino una referencia al objeto
$prueba2 = $prueba;

// se modifica el objeto referenciado
$prueba->despedida = 'adiós';

// todas las variables que lo referencian apuntan a su nuevo contenido
var_dump($prueba2);
```

Imprimirá un objeto donde `despedida` es `adiós` en vez de `chao`.

Si reasignaras el valor de `$prueba` no se tocaría el objeto, que sigue en memoria.

```
// esto crea un objeto en memoria, y $prueba es una referencia al objeto
$prueba = (object) ['saludo' => 'hola', 'despedida' => 'chao'];

// $prueba2 no es el valor del objeto, sino una referencia al objeto
$prueba2 = $prueba;

// se redeclara $prueba, la cual pierde la referencia al objeto
$prueba = 'cualquier cosa';

// $prueba2 sigue siendo una referencia al objeto en memoria
var_dump($prueba2);
```

Por lo cual `$prueba2` no vale `cualquier cosa` sino que devuelve el contenido del objeto referenciado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que esta pasando es que estas tratando de hacer una referencia y para eso se debe asignar el signo ampersand (&) al comienzo de la variable cuyo valor se está asignando.

```
$nombre = 'Juan';          // Asigna el valor 'Juan' a $nombre
$saludo = &$nombre;        // Referenciar $nombre vía $saludo.
$saludo = "Hola $saludo";  // Modifica $nombre...
echo $saludo;
echo $nombre;  // $nombre también se modifica.

// imprime Hola Juan y Hola Juan
```

Otro ejemplo que tambien publicaron es `var_dump` que por definición muestra información sobre una variable como por ejemplo:

```
$cadenadetexto = 'abc';
var_dump($cadenadetexto);
// que dará como resultado string(3) "abc"
```

Lo cual no creo que estes buscando eso.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu código deberia de ser así:

```
<?php

$prueba = "hola";
$prueba2 = & $prueba;

echo $prueba2; //Muestra hola

?>
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de2c749420d64ecd24a8232ed52efab1bc919c3a).

Answer (score -1):

He corregido espero que esto te ayude Elimina el `&` de tu código y déjalo así. El `&` se utiliza mas para concatenación de variables no para pasar el valor como lo intentaste.

```
 <?php
 $prueba="Hola";
 $prueba2="prueba";
 echo $$prueba2;
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

El doble **$** y **&** son innecesarios en tu caso.

```
   <?php 
$variable = "hola"; 
$variable2 = $variable; 
echo $variable2; 
?>
```

Comment: Ese no es un problema de sintaxis, el `$$` es algo completamente permitido en php y tiene una función distinta

Comment: Corregido, olvidé añadir comentario correcto.